# Invalid Python interpreter when using Pycharm to load a project in Dropbox which is created by a different computer

Tags: python, pycharm, dropbox, environment, pythoninterpreter

I use two Macs, one is at home and the other one at office. I installed Pycharm, hoping that I could load a same project using these two Macs. So I set the project folder to Dropbox, and everything could be synced immediately.

Note that I create a virtual environment in the project folder. In this folder, I could see all the site-packages and the Python executable. But when I try to load the project in the 2nd Mac, the alert goes, saying that the interpreter is invalid, as shown in the picture:
[image]

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Python environments aren't portable.

You should either use a docker image, or simply keep a `requirements.txt` file synchronized and use the local Python environment on both machines.